# Method for cryptanalysis of a keyword-keyletter cipher?

Tags: cryptanalysis, classical-cipher

I am a CS student who is in an introductory cryptography course. I am not looking for the complete plaintext of this message, as I am not looking to cheat. I am simply stuck and have no idea what to do for this part of an assignment.

I have attempted frequency analysis and have a link to it below. I have attempted substituting in E, T, trying trigraph THE, etc., at the most common points but have not been able to deduce anything. To my knowledge, there is no easy way to brute force this as I would have to try every keyword (170k words in the English language) at every position in the alphabet (42). It's possible but very inefficient.

We are instructed to launch a ciphertext-only attack on the given ciphertext. Our alphabet is 42 characters: 26 upper case English letters,10 digits, and 6 punctuation signs including "," (comma), "." (period), " (whitespace)", ";", ":", "!". This keyword cipher involves [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikiz4.png).

So far in the class, I have cracked an affine cipher and Vigenère using the Kasiski method. I have also done a couple of other coding projects. I have been searching for hours on ways to potentially tackle this variant of the keyword cipher, but I am at an utter loss. I am not seeking someone to decode the ciphertext but rather provide a possible way to tackle this or lead me in the right direction. Partial decryption is fine, but I really want to solve this on my own. I am trying to find the keyword, but ultimately I have to decrypt this. If I can somehow do that without finding out the keyword, that is a viable method. Our textbook thoroughly covered decryption methods for other ciphers, but it doesn't describe how to tackle this beyond frequency analysis, which I have been unsuccessful at.

Here is the [ciphertext](https://pastebin.com/bpVvCYMz).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFIsQ.png) is what I have done so far (Includes frequency analysis).